# How To Detect whether API request is coming from mobile app or web Using Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to customize my json response according to mobile app and web, to do so I need to check whether the request is coming from mobile app or web. so, is there any solution. And is it possible to sent separate json response to mobile app and web with same API request.

Comment: Well, make sure one of them sends the request to a different URL, or with a different parameter or header.

Comment: We use a parameter `"device_type":"ios/android/web"` for this